# Ember Data 2.1.0 ignores the links property in my JSON response

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Ember Data 2.1.0 ignores the links property in my JSON response and fires the following request instead:

```
/point_logs/3e5ff053422f40e3a8057fc5e8100c47
```

Also for each point log found it fires a single request. Instead I want it to fetch a collection of all point logs.

In Ember 1.x everything worked fine though. Looked everywhere for an answer but unfortunately I was unable to find a solution so far.

**Appliance Model**

```
var DirectObject = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    type: DS.attr('string'),
    createdDate: DS.attr('date'),
    modifiedDate: DS.attr('date'),
    deletedDate: DS.attr('date'),
    pointLog: DS.belongsTo('pointLog')
});
```

**Pointlog Model**

```
var PointLog = DS.Model.extend({
    unit: DS.attr('string'),
    type: DS.attr('string'),
    lastConsecutiveLogDate: DS.attr('date'),
    updatedDate: DS.attr('date'),
    directObject: DS.belongsTo('directObject')
});
```

**JSON Response**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "6dbcf32a3e064a36a1db4847329cc90d",
      "type": "appliance",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "3974737",
        "description": "",
        "type": "zz_misc",
        "createdDate": "2015-09-15T14:23:02.768Z",
        "modifiedDate": "2015-10-08T08:39:15.525Z",
        "deletedDate": null
      },
      "relationships": {
        "pointLog": {
          "data": {
            "id": "3e5ff053422f40e3a8057fc5e8100c47",
            "type": "pointLog"
          },
          "links": {
            "related": "/core/appliances/6dbcf32a3e064a36a1db4847329cc90d/point_log"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "included": [],
  "links": {
    "self": "/core/appliances"
  }
}
```

I've also tried using the self property instead of related. And also related as an object with an href property inside being the url.

Comment: Appliance extends the DirectObject model

Comment: How is your data being served? Is it async?  Just to clarify: you want to return multiple `pointLogs` for each appliance? Or vice versa?

Comment: @sbatson5 the call is async and indeed I want to return multiple pointLogs for each appliance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out. The problem is the data property. It seems that if it is present, Ember will make individual calls without using the url given in the links object.

**Before**

```
"relationships": {
  "pointLog": {
    "data": {
      "id": "3e5ff053422f40e3a8057fc5e8100c47",
      "type": "pointLog"
      },
      "links": {
        "related": "/core/appliances/6dbcf32a3e064a36a1db4847329cc90d/point_log"
    }
  } 
}
```

**After**

```
"relationships": {
  "pointLog": {
    "links": {
      "related": "/core/appliances/6dbcf32a3e064a36a1db4847329cc90d/point_log"
    }
  }
}
```